# Java 8 Streams groupingBy collector

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

How would I get this data structure using Java 8 API?

This is my object structure:

```
class A {

    B b;

    public A(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}

class B {

    List<A> as;

    private int i;

    public B(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to aggregate it to

```
 Map<A, List<B>> bs;
```

from

```
List<A> as = new ArrayList<>();
as.add(a1);
as.add(a2);
as.add(a3);
```

Comment: `as.stream().collect(groupingBy(a -> a.b))` - it would be neater to add a getter for `b` in `A` in order to use a method reference. You would also need `equals` and `hashCode` on `B`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With groupingBy:

```
Map<B, List<A>> bs = as.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(A::getB));
```

Assuming class `A` has a `getB()` method.

Comment: Unless `B` has a secret `equals` and `hashCode` that is not shown, and `A` has a secret `getB` that is not shown this isn't going to do very much of anything at all.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Yes, it would make sense for `B` to override `equals` and `hashCode`, but even if it doesn't, it will still perform grouping by the default implementation of `equals` and `hashCode` (for example, in the OP's sample code, two instances of `A` share the same instance of `B`, so they will be grouped together).

Comment: @Bharath Why would you need a `Map<A, List<B>> bs`? Wouldn't each `A` instance have a single `B` instance?

Comment: @Bharath If `A` has a reference to a single `B` instance. How can there be multiple `B`s associated with the same `A`?

Comment: i agree. my question is kind of wrong. :(. thanks though. i was trying to mimic a hibernate entity and forgot to add the onetomany relation on B.

Answer (score 7):

It's pretty simple actually (assuming `hashCode/equals` is present in `B`)

```
as.stream()
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(A::getB))
```

Comment: @BoristheSpider right, I mentioned the first one, the second was a guess